# hcitool can't maintain connections on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I'm trying to install bluez on a Raspberry Pi. It seems to work, but hcitool lecc always disconnects after ~2 seconds. This happens on a freshly installed os. I follow the steps listed here: http://www.elinux.org/RPi_Bluetooth_LE.

Installing bluez with apt-get instead of building the source seems to have fixed my problem.

```
sudo apt-get install bluez
```

Comment: Installing bluez with apt-get instead of building the source seems to have fixed my problem

Comment: Can you post an anwser with a tutorial/command? For future references?

Comment: Sure, I edited the main post to include the terminal command to use apt-get. Does that work for you?

Comment: No it didn't but it might be useful for other users in the future.

Comment: `hcitool` is deprecated and is in the process of being phased out of BlueZ, it also runs on non-maintained source code. You are better off using `bluetoothctl` or any newer tooling such as `btmgmt` included in newer releases of BlueZ. A lot of errors and problems with BlueZ, Bluetooth and Bluetooth LE come from people still using `hcitool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install bluez`

will fix this.

When I asked this question, there was no update bluez package in the repos that have bluetooth capability. I must have been compiling from source wrong